# Matching Exact string with regexp

Tags: java, regex

I have the following string:

```
CLASSIC STF
CLASSIC
```

am using regexp to match the strings.

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^CLASSIC(\\s*)$", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
```

`CLASSIC STF` is also being displayed.
am using `m.find()`
How is it possible that only `CLASSIC` is displayed not `CLASSIC STF`

Thanks for helping.

Comment: Have you looked at a solution that uses `$` and/or `^`?

Comment: @reto yup i have looked at.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use `Matcher.find()` the expression `CLASSIC(\s*)` will match `CLASSIC STF`.
`Matcher.matches()` will return false, however, since it requires the expression to match the *entire* input.

To make `Matcher.find()` do the same, change the expression to `^CLASSIC(\s*)$`, as said by reto.

Comment: I believe this answer is incorrect. Or at least I don't understand it. "CLASSIC(\s*)" will not match "CLASSIC STF" (it will match the first 8 characters only), so the opening statement is incorrect. "\s" matches whitspace characters.

Comment: @Rinke that depends on how you define _matches_: if you use `Matcher.matches()` then your statement is correct, since the _entire_ input has to match. However, if you're using `Matcher.find()` `CLASSIC(\s*)` _will_ be found in `CLASSIC STF` (since even `CLASSIC` itself would match). Generally, a regular expression matches any substring, i.e. the most common form is what `find()` does.

Comment: Ok, I see your point. I guess I'd say that `Matcher.find()` would match a *substring* of "CLASSIC STF", but not the string itself. The latter would be misleading in my opinion. Thanks for the clarification in any case.

Answer (score 2):

By default `^` and `$` match against the beginning and end of the entire input string respectively, ignoring any newlines. I would expect that your expression would not match on the string you mention. Indeed:

```java
String pattern = "^CLASSIC(\\s*)$";
String input = "CLASSIC STF%nCLASSIC";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(pattern, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
Matcher m = p.matcher(String.format(input));
while (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group());
}
```

prints no results.

If you want `^` and `$` to match the beginning and end of all lines in the string you should enable "multiline mode". Do so by replacing line 3 above with `Pattern p = Pattern.compile(pattern, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE + Pattern.MULTILINE);`. When I do so I get one result, namely: "CLASSIC".

You also asked why "CLASSIC STF" is not matched. Let's break down your pattern to see why. The pattern says: match anything that...

1. starts at the beginning of a line ~ `^`
2. begins with a C, followed by an L, A, S, S, I and C ~ `CLASSIC`
3. after which 0 or more whitespace characters follow ~ `(\s*)`
4. after which we see a line ending ~ `$`

After matching the space in "CLASSIC STF" (step 3) we are looking at a character "S". This doesn't match a line ending (step 4), so we cannot match the regex.

Note that the parentheses in your regex are not necessary. You can leave them out.

[The Javadoc of the Pattern class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) is very elaborate. It could be helpful to read it.

**EDIT:**

If you want to check if a string/line contains the word "CLASSIC" using a regex, then I'd recommend to use the regex `\bCLASSIC\b`. If you want to see if a string starts with the word "CLASSIC", then I'd use `^CLASSIC\b`.

Answer (score 1):

I wonder if this would help:
practice = c("CLASSIC STF", "CLASSIC")
grep("^CLASSIC[[:space:]STF]?", practice)